# Using Value of String vs. Using Actual String in Command

Tags: r, string, data-wrangling

I have a string that I want to use in a command and want to loop through 100s of the InputIs variables. In this simplified version, I have an example of what doesn't work and a version that does work. My output variable is never collapsed and is a single file name. The input never works, even when there is only a single value (pdf file) in the string.

```
InputIs <- '"AV_SEVER_0002005.pdf","AV_SEVER_0002006.pdf","AV_SEVER_0002007.pdf"'
print(InputIs)
OutputIs <- "AV_SEVER_0002005.pdf"
print(OutputIs)
## I don't work
qpdf::pdf_combine(input=c(InputIs), output = paste("Final\\\\",OutputIs,sep=""))

## I work!   
qpdf::pdf_combine(input=c("AV_SEVER_0002005.pdf","AV_SEVER_0002006.pdf","AV_SEVER_0002007.pdf"), output = paste("Final\\\\",OutputIs,sep=""))
```

I believe there is a better way to call on the string within the command and think that is where this falls apart. Thank you!

Comment: How are you building the value of `InputIs` in the first place? The fact that your commas are inside the quotes vs outside the quoted string makes a big difference. R is not a macro style language. You shouldn't just swap text and code without parsing it. You want `inputIDs` to be a vector with a length equal to the number of files you want to combine, not a single string of length 1 as you currently have it.

Comment: can you share `OutputIs`

Comment: Shared OutputIs in an edit to the codeblock.

@MrFlick - In the example I am just using a string and it doesn't work. In my larger project, I am collapsing in a paste through dplyr::summarize. The results are the same. I see what you are saying about a single string vs. a vector of the parts equal to the files to combine. I thought building the string to use in the command was the way to go, but appears not. Open to ideas.

Comment: Don't collapse the list into a string. Pass the vector as input.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks. Took a bit, but finally mashed this out from the gsub on to the )))) to 'vectorise' the input: qpdf::pdf_combine(input = c(gsub('"',"",unlist(strsplit(rowIs$FilesAreNow,", ")))), output = paste("Final\\\\",OutputIs,sep=""))